# Issue with Makefile target rule and PHONY

Tags: makefile

> I know this could be done in different ways, but I am actually looking for learning more about makefiles.

I want to be able to call `make somefile.txt` and run a given script.

In my current folder I have:

**makefile**

```
%.txt:
    # perl -pe "s/#.*//g; s/^\n//g; s/\n/\t/g;" .txt
    echo "Hi"
```

When I call `make`, I am getting

`` make: `somefile.txt' is up to date. ``

I know I would need to use `.PHONY`, but I am having trouble trying to use it with `%.txt`.

I already tried things such as

```
files = *.txt
.PHONY = $(files)
%.txt:
    # perl -pe "s/#.*//g; s/^\n//g; s/\n/\t/g;" .txt
    echo "Hi"
```

But that didn't actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (a) conventional way to do this is to make your real target have a phony one as a prerequisite.  Phony targets are always considered initially out of date, so anything that depends on a phony target will also always be considered out of date.  "force" is a conventional name for a target used for this purpose.

For example,

```
.PHONY: force

force:

%.txt: force
        echo "Hi at $$(date)" > $@
```

As demonstrated in the example, this does not require the phony target to have a recipe.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to list your targets to be built in your makefile but instead just give them on the command line, you can use this:

```
.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

The [variable `MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) will be set to the set of goals you gave make on the command line.

It's important to understand that a makefile is not the shell, and so just sticking `*.txt` anywhere in your makefile won't always expand it.  Only particular areas of the makefile work with shell globs directly.

If you want to always expand it, you can use make's `wildcard` function like this:

```
files = $(wildcard *.txt)
```

Comment: In this case, what would be the proper way to use files or .PHONY? I used this variable `file` you posted. But it didn't seem to work. I am still checking on `MAKECMDGOALS`

Comment: You would say `.PHONY: $(files)`.  That means any _already existing_ `*.txt` file will be considered phony.